# Написать между тегами TD "1", которая указана в TR id

Tags: html, javascript

Есть следующий код:

> `<table>
> <tbody>
> <tr id="1"><td></td></tr>
> <tr id="2"><td></td></tr>
> <tr id="3"><td></td></tr>
> </tbody>
> </table>`

Как через Javascript сделать код, который между тегами TD напишет id тэга TR? В итоге в первой строчке должно быть "1", во второй "2" и так далее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хм... Как-то так:

```
function view(){ // Функция рендера ID, как вызвать будешь - это твоя фантазия
 var tr = document.querySelector('table tr'); // Ищем строки
 for(var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) // Проходим по всем строкам
  tr[i].querySelector('td:first').innerHTML = tr[i].id; // Ищем в строке первую ячейку и помещаем туда ID
}
```